# Exporting HTML file from Cordova app in a manner that works in both IOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, cordova

I have a cordova app which offers a journal function. Users store questions and programmatically generated answers to local storage, which are presented in a rich html page through a Webview.

Some users have asked for the ability to export that file for safekeeping. I want to implement one javascript solution which works in either IOS or Android.  So I need a solution that doesn't depend on a local file system (because IOS won't allow that).

I thought about creating an email a user can send to themselves. I could generate a pdf with one of the pdf libraries, but RFC 2368 says I can't attach that as attachments are not allowed in the mailto URL scheme. I can't put html in the body of a mailto email either, RFC 2368 again.

The local storage data is butt-ugly: I don't want to send raw data or JSON strings to an end user, and while I could render a plain-text mailto body, I'd have to lose images and just lay out some very long URLs in plain text and cross fingers that the client will render them as links.

A webview browser page can't be saved.

So what am I missing? What's the single genius solution for taking a web page that exists in local storage and providing the user a way to store it locally on a computer or snag it from a server, regardless of the device or operating system of their phone or tablet?

Comment: I'm using cordova-plugin-file to store files on the device. It works -- even on iOS -- but as you say, it's ugly. Users have to take to Android File Transfer or File Sharing in iTunes to get the files off the device. Definitely let us know what you decide on, because it looks like there are a ton of alternatives out there.